# using the default mail/send button

Tags: ios, uibutton, rounded-corners

I'm searching for the default `mail name button` or the `send button` if i write an sms.
Is it possible to use them, call them programmatically?
Or can I only build them from UIButtonTypeCustom?
I'm simply want to have a button exactly like the UIButtonTypeRoundedRect but with total round corners.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the QuartzCore Framework you can call..

```
MyButton.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(MyButton.frame) * 0.5;
```

Comment: should be MyButton.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetHeight(MyButton.frame) * 0.5;

Comment: @atreat correct, it should be half the height of the button frame.

Comment: but i have to create my own button, right? because I simply want to use the roundedRectButton with its hover, lableColor ...

Comment: You use a customButton in ib, connect it to your viewController as a property and then call the function on viewDidLoad, done. Next step would be making you own UIButton subclass and use that code at initialization.